# How to reboot instance as a root shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, centos6

I cannot login as a root user by entering the command "sudo -s".
When I run "sudo -s"

The console shows as below

sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner

sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins

I have already tried the commands:

pkexec chmod go-w /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

This doesn't help.

So I want to reboot my instance as a root shell to change the file permission, however I could not find the way to reboot as a root shell.

Comment: Reboot the instance using the Google Cloud Console, or using the CLI `gcloud`. You will of course need the Google IAM permissions to do this.

Comment: Try executing the command `sudo su` it will give you super user permissions and must change the user to root

Answer (score 1):

I am using an Ubuntu 16.04.5 (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1023 x86_64) After logging in you can try:

$ sudo su -

Then execute the commands of your choice, for a shutdown you can try a "shutdown" command as an example.

By [default](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#root), the /etc/ssh/sshd_config SSH configuration file has the "PermitRootLogin" parameter set to "no", which do not allow root login.